# CSS mask-image with linear gradient not working in Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Caniuse.com says that Edge has full support for mask-image but the following code is working in all browsers for me except Edge.

```
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

This should produce a simple red box which is red a the top and transparent at the bottom. Tested in Chrome and Firefox with no problems.

So, is it just incompatible with linear-gradient? I have scoured the web but can't find an answer.

Comment: you can create this with simple gradient as background without mask

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif but I've simplified my use case to post on here. In reality the div will contain html content that needs masking, not just a solid color.

Comment: you can post your real use case, we probably find some workarounds ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my testing code.

```
    #masked {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
        -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
<div id="masked"></div>
```

I've found that if I do not add -webkit-mask-image, when running on Chrome, there will be no transparent at the bottom.

But it always works well on Edge.

My version is Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0,Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763.

[image: work well on Edge]

Comment: Thanks Jenifer. How have you managed to get version 18 of Edge? I've done every upgrade of Windows 10 I can but still get version 17.

Comment: Mine Edge is updated as the system is updated. Maybe you could go to system setting to check the update.

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize that it uses alpha channels instead of a b/w image

Answer (score 2):

According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask), `mask-image` is supported in Edge 18, but is hidden behind a flag in lower versions.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought I had the latest version (I've never refused any updates) but it must be newer than I thought.

Comment: Ah, bit quick to mark that as the correct answer, sorry. I've set the flag "CSS Masking" in Edge 17 but unfortunately it still doesn't work. The whole div is red.

Comment: @jonhobbs It doesn't seem to work correctly. For me, Edge keeps crashing when I try to use mask-image.

Comment: Yeah, dev tools crashes for me every time but the browser still works. By the time my project launches Edge will probably have officially switched to chromium rendering engine but I still have to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Couple additional things:

If you're doing this on a `picture` element you need to add it on the `img` and not the containing `picture`.

Even in 2022 you still need `-webkit-mask-image`. Preprocessors should add this though.

If you have been using custom properties such as `--theme-color: red` make sure you only add a single dash for `-webkit` and not the double dash my stupid brain automatically entered for me today.